# C++ Stringstream only picking up first string

Tags: c++, string, stream

I have a text file with a series two strings delimited by a colon on each line.

I'm using getline to grab the entire line then string stream to split the two strings and put them onto a vector. The code works fine on the first pass it grabs the strings perfectly.  Then after that on the 2nd pass of the while loop and so forth it doesn't grab the new input. The string stream seems to leave the original first values for some reason.

```
 if (infile.is_open()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string current_line;
    std::string tempProxy;
    std::string tempPort;

    while (std::getline(infile, current_line)) {
        ss << current_line;
        std::getline(ss, tempProxy, ':');
        std::getline(ss, tempPort);
        std::cout << tempProxy << " and " << tempPort << std::endl;
    }
```

Any idea why it doesn't want to grab the strings from current_line on any pass except the first iteration?

Comment: Why is `ss`,`tempProxy` and `tempPort` in the outer scope? Why is `ss` not `std::istringstream` simply constructed from `current_line`?

Comment: That's odd, I thought constructing the stringstream once outside the loop and using the >> operator to feed it a new stream would be more efficient than constructing it each pass through the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reusing `ss` but not resetting it correctly. When you extract the second word from the first line, the stream is exhausted and put in an 'EOF' state. When streams are in this or any other 'error' state they don't do anything. You have to clear the error before you can continue to use them.

If you were to check for errors returned by `operator<<` and `getline` in the loop (or if you were to cause `ss` to throw exceptions on errors*) you would find they are indicating that they are not successful past the first iteration. It's a good general practice to always check for errors, and especially so when you're debugging.

You can clear the error by changing your loop:

```
while (std::getline(infile, current_line)) {
    ss.clear(); // clears the error, not the contents
    ss << current_line;
```

However doing this means that `ss` will accumulate all the lines in its internal buffer. The code will produce your expected output unless the file is large and you run out of memory or something like that.

You can see the accumulating internal buffer with the following:

```
while (std::getline(infile, current_line)) {
    ss.clear();
    ss << current_line;
    std::cout << "ss internal buffer: " << ss.str();
```

Instead of using the formatted input to add `ss` you are probably better off using the `.str()` member to set it, which will replace the previous data instead of adding to it.

```
while (std::getline(infile, current_line)) {
    ss.clear();
    ss.str(current_line);
```

Alternatively you can construct a new `stringstream` in each iteration of the loop. This does ensure that no error states or data are carried over from previous iterations. It may also be slower, but you'll have to profile that for yourself.

```
while (std::getline(infile, current_line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(current_line);
```

---

* Exceptions are nice because you don't need to remember to check them... except in cases like this where they're not enabled by default. Also I've noticed some C++ implementations have bugs in their iostreams exception code because people don't use it much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
 if (infile.is_open()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string current_line;
    std::string tempProxy;
    std::string tempPort;

    while (std::getline(infile, current_line)) {
        std::stringstream to_split;
        to_split.str(current_line);
        std::getline(to_split, tempProxy, ':');
        std::getline(to_split, tempPort);
        std::cout << tempProxy << " and " << tempPort << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: That's odd, I thought constructing the stringstream once outside the loop and using the >> operator to feed it a new stream would be more efficient than constructing it each pass through the loop. But it only seems to work your way rather than mine.